# найдите боковое ребро призмы

Tags: геометрия

высота наклонной призмы равна 2 корень из 3, найдите боковое ребро призмы, если она образует с плоскостью основания угол 60 °

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что такая геометрия не относится к программированию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если угол призмы с поверхностью 60, то синус этого угла равен корню из трёх пополам. Так как вы ищите гипотенузу то необходимо высоту поделить на синус, что равняется 2*sqrt(3) / (sqrt(3)/2) = 4